# cloud 9 JsHint how to recognize objects defined in other files

Tags: jshint, cloud9-ide

I have two java script files one defines an object

```
function Alliance(teamOneNumber,teamTwoNumber)
{
     /*implementation*/
}
```

And I use it in another file like this

```
function compute(r1,r2)
{
     var red = new Alliance(r1,r2);
     /*implementation*/
}
```

How do I get JsHint to recognize that Alliance is defined in another file. Instead of warning me that Alliance is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `global` directive (or look up how to configure "globals" in whatever plugin you're using):

```
/*global Alliance: false */
function compute(r1,r2)
{
     var red = new Alliance(r1,r2);
     /*implementation*/
}
```

The `false` indicates that `Alliance` cannot be assigned to in this scope. If you do need the ability to assign to it you can use `true` instead.